# Is it possible to access functions within a WPF applications using HTML5?

Tags: c#, wpf, html

I am still a noob so i really need help please.Is it possible to access functions within a WPF applications using HTML5?

So Basically i have a WPF application running on the same server and it has a print function. I want to add a html layer to this so the function can be executed via the html layer.

Comment: What do you mean by functions? You really need to provide more context. Where does your application run? What kind of application is it? It's way too vague.

Comment: Short answer No! They are very different technology. HTML5 doesn't have functions, is just HTML, what as functions is javascript, and the best thing you could do with both technologys is place a webbrowser control in wpf and call a website and in that website call a javascript function, the oposite, javascript call wpf methods is very difficult but you could read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/130267/Call-a-C-Method-From-JavaScript-Hosted-in-a-WebBro) article.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, The WPF is running on a server it is a information system that works with scanner and printer and touch screen inputs. I would like to access the wpf application by using a html5 layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have found some sort of solution to my predicament,
Have a look at this [site](http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/04/wpf-over-web-sockets-how-to-pump-wpf.html)

HTML5 Websockets And Canvas is what he use and give a good explanation. Hope you guys find it useful

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 Websockets And Canvas
With Websockets in HTML5, we are going beyond the unidirectional, stateless http to a full duplex, high speed connection infrastructure between the server and the client. - See more at: http://www.amazedsaint.com/2011/04/wpf-over-web-sockets-how-to-pump-wpf.html#sthash.vNEk0h8M.dpuf